# A faster way to count the number of Markdown links

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` containing reddit comments. Each comment may contains many Markdown links. For example,

```
'[a](https://www.google.com/) bcd [e](https://pandas.pydata.org/)'
```

I want to count such links. My approach is `df['comment'].str.count('\[(?P<txt>[^\]]+)\]\((?P<lnk>[^\)]+)\)')`.

Because my dataframe contains over 4 million rows, I would like to ask if there is a possibly faster way to so. Thank you so much!

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2],
     'comment': ['[a](https://www.google.com/) bcd [e](https://pandas.pydata.org/)',
                 '[f](https://www.google.com.vn/) bcd [g](https://pandas.pydata.org/)'
                ]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['comment'].str.count('\[(?P<txt>[^\]]+)\]\((?P<lnk>[^\)]+)\)')
```

Comment: How long does it take you currently? Have you searched for that? What did you find?

Comment: I think you could slightly improve pattern performance by simplifying it: `\[[^\]]+\]\([^\)]+\)` Besides that, I think it cannot be much more improved.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I extract the text from the link with `.replace('\[(?P<txt>[^\]]+)\]\((?P<lnk>[^\)]+)\)', '\g<txt>')`. It seems to me this extraction can be a little bit faster by combining with your `\[[^\]]+\]\([^\)]+\)`. Can you adjust it for this extraction?

Comment: Well, you need just one group, so I'd drop the other, still should be slight performance gain: `\[(?P<txt>[^\]]+)\]\([^\)]+\)`

Comment: Let me know if it's faster :)

Comment: Another pattern to test uses lookahead: `\[[^\]]+\](?=\([^\)]+\))` Then it is enough to extract matched text

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, regarding the text extraction, your method is `10.006367921829224 -  9.432971477508545` faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gain on performance I'd drop capturing groups.

But, as OP stated in comments, needs first capturing gropup. So I see two approaches here:

1. Dropping unnecessary capturing group and optionally removing named group:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]\([^\)]+\)
```

Then replacment pattern should be `\1` (just group reference)

2. Using lookahead and capturing only needed text:

```
\[[^\]]+\](?=\([^\)]+\))
```

Comment: How faster you think it is? Based on which test concluded it is faster?

Comment: @user12750353 Removing complexity always gains performance. Also, OP tested it

Comment: I tested here, but only 10% reduction when it matches, this is why I asked.